# Написать метод, возвращающий массив с заданными параметрами

Tags: java, массивы

Написать метод, принимающий на вход два аргумента: `len` и `initialValue`, и возвращающий одномерный массив типа `int` длиной `len`, каждая ячейка которого равна `initialValue`.

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1284674/edit) ваш вопрос, добавьте код, который вы попробовали написать. И напишите конкретно, с какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

Answer (score 1):

Метод, возвращающий одномерный массив типа `int` длиной `len`, каждая ячейка которого равна `initialValue`:

```
public static int[] retLenArr (int len, int initialValue){
    int arr[] = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = initialValue;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Метод позволяет вывести массив в консоль:

```
public static void printArrayInConsole(int[] inputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(inputArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Имея эти два метода вызываем их в паре:

```
printArrayInConsole(retLenArr(длинна массива, значение индексов));
```

Answer (score 0):

Изучите циклы. Они предназначены для этого. Выполняется задача следующим образом:

1. Создаёте массив int длины `len` *(гуглим, как это делать, это очень просто)*.
2. В цикле проходим весь массив и устанавливаем в каждую ячейку значение `initialValue` *(тоже гуглим, тоже очень просто, примеров в интернете миллиард)*

Короче, вам надо изучить следующее: циклы и массивы. Всё, больше в задаче ничего не надо.

Comment: "   public static int[] task(int len, int  initialValue) {
        int [] arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = initialValue;
            arr.length = len;
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

        return arr;
    }"

Comment: @SergeShein не будет работать. Вы неправильно создали массив и неправильно присваиваете значение его ячейкам.

Comment: а в чем ошибка в создании массива? 
и как присвоить значение тогда?

Comment: @SergeShein я не знаю, какой у вас уровень, поэтому мне будет сложно объяснить так, чтобы вам было понятно. Во-первых вы нигде не инициализируете массив. Вы только создали ссылку, но она пустая и ни на что не ссылается, у неё нет объекта. Во-вторых вы неправильно установили длину массива (вытекает из первой ошибки, т.к. длина задаётся при создании массива, а вы его не создали). Зачем-то пытаетесь установить длину массива равную len, причём неправильно, да ещё и в цикле???

Comment: @SergeShein я бы рекомендовал вам изучить последовательно темы "переменные и примитивы в java", "массивы", "объекты, создание объектов", "циклы". Например, на javarush или на любом другом сайте.